# c#: how to extend propertygrid to show a textbox on top

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid

i must create a "searchable" property grid, that is a textbox placed on the top followed by property grid.
Rather then using a user control i would extend property grid directly, but i' m not able to add a child textbox control on the fly.
Anyone can help me?
Thank you a lot!

Comment: Why not add it at the start and just change the visibility

Comment: please could you give me an example?

Comment: initially set `myTextBox.Visible = false;` then, when you want it to show, simply say `myTextBox.Visible = true;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PropertyGrid` internal control creation flow is undocumented. It's composed by a `ToolStrip`, a internal grid, the description pane and the action pane.

I tried to add a control to this existing collection : it causes issues in the whole control layout which seems to be done by some internal custom calculations, rather than the existing well-known NET layout mechanism.

It could probably be enforced by using Reflection, but I dont even have tried it because it would be hard on one hand, and on the other it would compromise the ascending compatability of future releases of the `PropertyGrid`.

I ended up using a `UserControl` where I put a top-docked `TextBox`, with a fill-docked `PropertyGrid`, and added this property :

```
public PropertyGrid InnerPropertyGrid
{
    get
    {
        return this.propertyGrid1;
    }
}
```

By this way, all my `PropertyGrid` properties, methods and events are exposed, **even during design mode**.

It is not the smartest way to do, but it's quicker and easier than trying to hack some private parts of this control.

Comment: Hello! this is my actual solution also. my hope was to  remove a control nesting, but i think now that it is too expensive!

Comment: I even tried to add a Item to the internal ToolStrip... It accepts button and label, but it does not understand the TextBoxToolStripItem... This is a nightmare :) So I stick with this and I'm quite happy anyway.